# Logging operation WP7 + WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-7

I'm working on an WP7 App that is connecting DB using WCF. I'm thinking how to perform logging. User data and passwd is in DB. I need a simple, non complicated way to do this. I have went through plenty of tutorials,examples etc but it didn't helped. Can anyone direct me the way how to log in? I realized that I haven't done this and don't have clue how to perform such operation.

My idea was to write something like this, but i don't think this is the good way to do this operation:
this is on the WCF Service side

```
    public bool LogIn(string userId, string passwd)
    {
        Boolean prompt = false;
        /*User user = new User();
        user.userId = userId;
        user.passwd = passwd;
        return user;*/
        ProgDBEntities context = new ProgDBEntities();
        var userEntity = (from p in context.UserEntity
                          where p.UserID == userId && p.Passwd == passwd
                          select p);
        if (userEntity != null)
        {
            prompt = true;

        }
        else
        {
            prompt = false;
            throw new Exception("No User in Database");
        }
        return prompt;

    }
```

in the side of WP7 Client i have textbox, passwordbox and log in button

EDIT:
So I decided to leave this code on WCF Service. Now the problem is that when I test it with WCFTestClient it always returns true...
I assume that something is wrong with this statement

```
    if (userEntity != null)
```

Comment: I guess its good to go with this implementation. Where you think its lacking on some point So I can help you on that

Comment: I'm just wondering if it would be better to f.e return user data instead of Boolean answear.
And I'm not pretty sure how to call this on the client side.

Comment: But in the other hand, bool is better for me, because when logging is succesful I want to navigate to other screen